# OD Cost Matrix snapping distance using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, origin-destination

I am using the ArcGIS Network Analysis - OD Cost Matrix layer tool and I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to incorporate the snapping distance of the origin and destination to my total distance value.  Right now, the Origin snaps to the closest line feature in my network and the same for the destination point, and the tool only gives me a distance between these 2 snapping points, but I would like to include the 2 snap distances as well.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I know I could use the Near command ontop of this tool to get the total distance, but I was hoping there was a setting in Network Analyst that could solve my problem.